# WinSCP script to synchronize directories, but exclude several subdirectories

Tags: sftp, winscp

I need to write a script that synchronizes local files with a remote machine.

My file structure is:

```
ProjectFolder/
    .git/
    input/
    output/
    classes/
    main.py
    readme.md
```

I need to synchronize everything, but:

1. completely ignore `.git` folder
2. ignore files in `input` and `output` folders, but copy the folder

So far my code is:

```
open sftp://me:password@server -hostkey="XXXXXXXX"

option batch abort
option confirm off
    
synchronize remote "C:\Users\MYNAME\Documents\MY FOLDER\Python Projects\ProjectFolder" "/home/MYNAME/py_proj/ProjectFolder" -filemask="|C:\Users\MYNAME\Documents\MY FOLDER\Python Projects\ProjectFolder\.git"
    
close
exit
```

First question: it doesn't seems to work.
Second question, how to add mask for input and output folder if I have spaces in file paths?

Thanks to all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Masks for directories](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#directory) have to end with a slash.
2. To exclude [files in a specific folder](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#path), use something like `*/folder/*`

```
-filemask="|.git\;*/input/*;*/output/*"
```

Comment: Sorry, was testing yesterday, didn't pay attention that I didn't finished comment. Your advice worked perfectly, there was a mistake on my part. Thank you very much for your input. Please disregard my first comment.